# Cloud functions timeout on page.goto()

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, serverless

I run tests with puppeteer in cloud functions.
If I run test on local machine all is fine. If I run tests in cloud functions emulator it's fine as well. But when I deploy my function to the cloud all tests stuck on
`page.goto('https://...')`
and function fails by timeout, which in my case is 3 minutes.

Comment: Without seeing code that anyone can use to reproduce to problem, it's not likely you'll get any help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.
And if you try any other website, like lets say `google.com` will it work ?

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii see the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in puppeteer. I downgraded from the version 1.13.0 to 1.11.0 and now everything works fine. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3944)

Comment: Congratulations on finding the solution to your question. As soon as you are able to, please mark it as solution to give the question more visibility.